# Leitura de log JBoss

Tags: java, log

Esse código pega o meu arquivo de *log* do JBoss e exibe as 1000 primeiras linhas. Queria saber como faço para exibir as ultimas 1000 linhas?

```
private String log;

public void pesquisar() {

    String diretorioCorrente = System.getProperty("jboss.server.log.dir");

    File file = new File(diretorioCorrente + File.separator + "server.log");
    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String linha;
        int contador = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((linha = input.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(linha + "\n");
            contador++;
            if (contador > 1001) {
                break;
            }
        }
        input.close();
        log = sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
}
```

Comment: Retira esse if: if(contador > 1001){break;}. E verifica se ele vai ler as outras linhas.

Answer (score 2):

### A má notícia

Você terá que ler todo o arquivo para recuperar as últimas linhas.

### A boa notícia

Com as classes da API collections do Java fica fácil recuperar as últimas `N` linhas.

### Procedimento

Primeiro, declare um `ArrayList` antes do `while` e adicione cada linha na lista ao invés do `StringBuffer`.

Em seguida, remova o critério de parada `if (contador > 1001)`, como já sugeriu o `@adelmo00`.

Dessa forma, seu método retornará todas as linhas, certo?

Finalmente, remova do vetor as linhas mais "antigas" quando o número destas passar de 1000. Exemplo:

```java
public void pesquisar() {

    String diretorioCorrente = System.getProperty("jboss.server.log.dir");

    File file = new File(diretorioCorrente + File.separator + "server.log");
    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String linha;
        int contador = 0;
        //inicia com um array interno de 1000 posições
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(1000); 
        //adiciona todos os elementos, mas quando chegar a 1000, remove os mais velhos
        while ((linha = input.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(linha);
            contador++;
            if (contador > 1000) {
                linha.remove(0);
            }
        }
        //escreve no StringBuffer, mas talvez não seja necessário
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String str : list) {
            sb.append(str + "\n");
        }
        input.close();
        log = sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
}
```